# Jquery select in dart and angularjs 2

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dart, angular

I am working with Dart and Angularjs 2, I want to use select2 the view but it is not working, my code is:

code in html

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="nivelEducativo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nivel Educativo</label>
 <div class="col-sm-4">
 <select class="select_profession form-control" id="nivelEducativo" 
*ngIf="paramsByTypeCode != null" [(ngModel)]="model.situacionEducativaId">
     <option *ngFor="#param of paramsByTypeCode['PRT014']" 
    value="{{param.id}}">{{param.nombre}}</option>
 </select>
 </div>
</div>
...
<script>
  function __selectProfession(selector) {
    $(selector).select2({
    placeholder: "Select One",
    allowClear: true
  });
 }
</script>
```

code in Dart

```
  void ngAfterViewInit(){
    new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 1),()=>js.context.callMethod('__selectProfession',[".select_profession"]));
  }
```

The select2 doesn't work, but if I remove ngIf tag the select2 works but it doesn't show the list of professions, the select2 works well without angular2. I want to know,so how can I work with it?.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
*ngIf="paramsByTypeCode != null"
```

use

```
[hidden]="paramsByTypeCode == null"
```

Then the element exists even when `paramsByTypeCode` is `null` otherwise `*ngIf` removes it from the DOM and jQuery can't find it.

I'm not sure what the intention of this code is

```
 new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 1),()=>js.context.callMethod('__selectProfession',[".select_profession"]));
```

but I guess it should be

```
 new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 1),()=>js.context.callMethod('__selectProfession',[".select_profession"]));
```

Comment: I put the tag [hidden] , but it is the same, the select2 is called but the list of profession is not shown, it is empty, with tag ngif the list is not empty but it doesn't work as select2

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker? I'm not familiar with these widgets but I could have a looks what's going on if you provide a Plunker.